# Yii2 ActiveForm doesn't want to send through post

Tags: yii2

I have an `ActiveForm` which do not want to send data through the `$_POST`. All the data is send by `$_GET` even when i made it like that:

```
    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use backend\models\Lang;
use backend\models\View;
use backend\models\Page;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use jlorente\remainingcharacters\RemainingCharacters;
use backend\components\OutData;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Page */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array(
    'disabled' => false,
    'uploadURL' => "/media",
    'uploadDir' => Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . "/media/",
);
?>

<div class="panel-wrapper collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="form-body">
                <h3 class="box-title">Информация</h3>
                <hr>

                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'update-form',
                        'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['page/create']),
                        'method' => "post",
                ]); ?>

                <?php $languages = Lang::find()->all(); ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <?php
        foreach ($languages as $key => $language) {
            if ($language->default == 1) {
                echo '<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' . $key . '">' . $language->name . '</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' . $key . '">' . $language->name . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php
        foreach ($languages as $key => $language) {
            if ($language->default != 1) {
                echo '<div id="' . $key . '" class="tab-pane fade">';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'title_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'url_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_title_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_description_' . $language->url)->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div col-xs-12><div class="form-group">';
                $textContent = 'content_' . $language->url;
                if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
                    $model->$textContent = OutData::showTXT($model->$textContent);
                }
                echo $form->field($model, 'content_' . $language->url)->textarea();
                echo "<script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'Page[content_$language->url]' );
                    </script>";
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div id="' . $key . '" class="tab-pane fade in active">';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'title')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'url')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_title')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group">';
                echo $form->field($model, 'meta_description')->widget(RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
                            'type' => RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXT,
                            'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
                            'label' => [
                                'tag' => 'p',
                                'id' => 'my-counter',
                                'class' => 'myCounter',
                                'invalidClass' => 'error'
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]
                        ]);
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="form-group">';
                if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
                    $model->content = OutData::showTXT($model->content);
                }
                echo $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea();
                echo "<script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'Page[content]' );
                    </script>";
                echo '</div></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php
            $mas[0] = Yii::t('app', 'Главна страница');
            $mas['----------------'] = ArrayHelper::map(Page::find()->where('id_in=0 and is_cat=1')->all(), 'id', 'title');
            ?>
            <?=
            $form->field($model, 'id_in')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'id_in',
                'data' => $mas,
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select a type ...'),
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ])
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php
            if ($model->isNewRecord) {
                echo $form->field($model, 'view_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => 12])->label(false);
            } else {
                echo $form->field($model, 'view_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => $model->view_id])->label(false);
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'sort')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'active')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->active) ? $model->active : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'active', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="active_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->active == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-active', 'active_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="active_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'in_main_menu')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->in_main_menu) ? $model->in_main_menu : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'in_main_menu', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->in_main_menu == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-in_main_menu', 'in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="in_main_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'in_side_menu')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->in_side_menu) ? $model->in_side_menu : 2])->label(false) ?>

            <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'in_side_menu', ['class' => 'dblock flLeft mr5 pt5']); ?>
            <label class="switch switch-custom block dblock flLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"class="legend-switch" <?= ($model->in_side_menu == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> onchange="changeHiddenField('page-in_side_menu', 'in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>');"></input>
                <label data-off="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Не'); ?>" data-on="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Да') ?>" for="in_side_menu_<?= $model->id ?>"></label>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'is_cat')->hiddenInput(['value' => ($model->is_cat) ? $model->is_cat : 0])->label(false) ?>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'app.Create') : Yii::t('app', 'app.Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<script>
    $('#w0').on('beforeValidate', function (event, messages, deferreds) {
        for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
        }
        return true;
    });
</script> 

<script>

    function selectView(view_id) {
        if (view_id == 9) {
            $('#page-is_cat').val(1);
        } else {
            $('#page-is_cat').val(0);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Is it something with my syntax? What can cause this kind of problem?
And this is my controller:

```
public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Page();
        $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        /*var_dump($_POST);die;*/
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model = $this->findModel($model->id, true);
            $languages = Lang::find()->all();
            foreach ($languages as $language) {
                if ($language->default != 1) {
                    $title = 'title_' . $language->url;
                    // $url = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->$title, $model->id);
                    $urlName = 'url_' . $language->url;
                    $model->$urlName = MakeURL::parseUrlGoogle($model->$urlName, $model->id);
                    $content = 'content_' . $language->url;
                    $var =  Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->$content);
                    $model->$content = $var;
                } else {
                    // $url = MakeURL::parseUrl($model->title, $model->id);
                    $model->url = MakeURL::parseUrlGoogle($model->url, $model->id);
                    $model->content = Yii::$app->OutData->sanitize($model->content);
                }
            }
            $model->old_link = 2;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**EDITED** With whole view.

Comment: Update your question with view code please.

Comment: Ready! The whole view is there :)

Comment: You have static <form> tag in your view file "<form action="#">". Remove that and then check.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! Thank you very much!